# JavaFX 2 TableView inserting rows directly on the control

Tags: tableview, javafx-2

Does the TableView Control in JavaFX 2 allow the insertion of new data right on the cells of the control?

I have not been able to find anything in that direction. Even the Oracle sample has separate textboxes and an ADD button outside of the control (like it was in the early 90's - yea, I've been programming for that long...)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what do you want to achieve.

If you mean editing table values in place you can take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/ui_controls/table-view.htm

If you want to add new row by action on cell you can add context menu to cells by `TableView.setContextMenu(context_menu);` and implement adding new row "right on the cells".

Comment: Hi Sergey. **Thanks for yor reply.** I want the user to be able to enter data just like in excel. Click on an empty cel, and enter new data....

Comment: Great, to achieve that you can follow `Editing Data in the Table` section of tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/ui_controls/table-view.htm#CJAGDAHE

Comment: Thanks again. I know this tutorial up and down. The "in place" editing applies ONLY to cells that allready have a value set. I know I can capture the mouse event, and do something with that, but before I spend hours of trial and error, wanted to understand that there is no existing functionality for this.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want clicking on not initialized cell to add all required rows from last till cell clicked and start edit on that cell. Unfortunately I don't know of existing implementation of this approach :(

Comment: Thanks Sergey!  I've changed taktics for the interface. I am very new to JavaFX and could benefit from having a tutor. Can I hire you?

Comment: just ask questions on stackoverflow and I'll help you  :)