# JavaFX - TableView, How to add new row to the control?

Tags: row, tableview, javafx-2, addition

Does anyone know how to add a new row (to add completely new data) to the TableView - directly to the control? Editing is quite easy, but how to add new data?

I thought this should not be a problem (as I know this from other prog. languages), but on the entire internet I have found only this one related topic posted a year ago which is not answered still. Is it imposible to do this in JavaFX?

[JavaFX 2 TableView inserting rows directly on the control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088213/javafx-2-tableview-inserting-rows-directly-on-the-control?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you mean you want to add a row with empty cells to edit them later?

Comment: may be helpful http://tiwulfx.panemu.com/

Comment: Sergey: Yes, I want to add a new row with empty cells to edit them right after the new empty row appears in table.

Comment: Invariant: Thank you very much for this tip, this control looks very good, this is exactly what i want to do...add a new row and edit it.

Answer (score 0):

TableView is backed by an [items list](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#getItems%28%29), add a new entry to the items list and a row corresponding to the entry will be displayed in the TableView.

```
tableView.getItems().add(new Item());
```

Comment: This would be great solution if it would work for non parametric constructor, but it works only when the data displayed in table are filled in constructor. The aim is to fill data straight in the table.